# How can I insert into multiple datasources with each repository call in Spring Boot and Hibernate?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Multiple Datasources insert for same Entity and same Repo

Requirement is to **insert into 2 different datasources with each repository call**.
Basically I need `customerReposity.save(customer)` to insert same `customer` object to 2 different datasources.
I studied about `AbstractRoutingDataSource` but the problem is it allows only 1 datasource for each lookup key. I can use `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()` to figure out lookup key as "read" or "write". Then I want a `List<Datasource>` for lookup key "write".

It's a full grown project where I want to use this. So duplicating `customerReposity.save(customer)` 2 times in each place where it's used, seems impossible to me.

Looking for an easier solution in **Spring Boot** for inserting into multiple db simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the mirroring of inserts and updates using Hibernate event listeners. Very well explained here: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/